# What is the purpose of laravels helper function str_finish?

Tags: php, laravel, function, helper

I just stumbled across the helper function [str_finish](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-str-finish) from the [laravel framework](https://laravel.com/).

How does this differ from a simple

```
$newString = 'some string' . 'END';
```

?

The function code is:

```
public static function finish($value, $cap)
{
    $quoted = preg_quote($cap, '/');
    return preg_replace('/(?:'.$quoted.')+$/u', '', $value).$cap;
}
```

What are the benefits of putting this seemingly basic, built-into PHP functionality into a separate function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does more than that, if the string is already finished by the given string, it doesn't append any more:

For example:

```
'abbc' === str_finish('ab', 'bc');
'abbc' === str_finish('abbcbc', 'bc');
'abcbbc' === str_finish('abcbbcbc', 'bc');
```

[Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/f0d417bfa7a2e78d70c7382bfc51fe02321f0a3e/tests/Support/SupportStrTest.php#L113)

Comment: Oh, sweet! That's what the RegeExp-magic actually does. The docs should really mention that, since it's not obvious even if you inspect the code, which shouldn't be necessary in the first place.